# Для чего GCM требует GET_ACCOUNTS разрешение?

Tags: java, android

Суть вопроса в том, что мне нужно поставить динамическую проверку этого пермишена и я не могу понять где точно ее нужно поставить , так как и без этого пермишена все работает нормально.

Как можно проверить в какой момент какие пермишены запрашиваются?

А то я подумываю удалить его если и так работает, так как помню, что вроде писал этот пермишен когда реализовывал `GCM` и даже комментарий оставил

```
<!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
```

Но если пермишен удаляю, то ничего не меняется, странно...

Comment: на каких версиях оси пробовали?Может, на старых версиях он будет требовать?

Comment: @Asgard пробовал на 21 и на 23

Comment: попробуйте 16-19, это 4.0+ версии, до lolipop, может там будет разница.

Comment: @Asgard мое прложение работает с `Camera2API` , а оно требует апи не менее 21...

Comment: этот пермишн используется для доступа к аккаунтам, которые привязаны к девайсу. Раньше (до 4 версий андроида) он еще требовался для использования пушей, но потом это требование убрали. То есть можете удалять, ничего страшного

Comment: @АндроидАндроид да но там написано, что GCM это как то использует для доступа к гугл аккаунтам... Или если и так работает то можно удалить? Просто может я не до конца понимаю всей глубины вопроса, как и на что это может повлиять...

Comment: Да, можно удалить. Вот тут пишут http://stackoverflow.com/a/18444343/4829111